# Beta distribution: Sum of parameters

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, beta-function

I use the beta distribution with bounds 0,1 as an approximation for the distributions of answers in a survey. Do you know wether distributions who have different alpha/beta ratios but the same **sum** alpha+beta have some common properties, e.g. the distributions *Beta(3,7)* and *Beta(2,8)*? Has the sum of alpha and beta already been used or given an interpretation? I could not find anything.

Thank you!

Comment: If you take a simplistic approach and see $\alpha$ successes and $\beta$ failures leading to a $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ posterior distribution, then $\alpha + \beta$ would correspond to the number of previous attempts

Comment: Thank you, that acutally helped!